# Using "overflow: auto" on <table> parent element causes annoying word wrap in first column

Tags: html, css, css-tables, word-wrap

A web site of mine has tables nested within absolutely-positioned draggable dialogs that show/hide based on some user interactions.  It's worth mentioning that these tables have `table-layout: auto;` and `width: auto;`.  A problem arose where a table had so many rows that it went off the bottom edge of the screen.  This caused issues with the dragging since we have limited the dragging to the edges of the viewport.  To fix the issue, I wrapped the table in a `<div>` and set `max-height: 400px; overflow: auto;` on it.  This gives the user a nice vertical scroll bar whenever the table exceeds the max-height.  That works, but for some reason the browser (both IE and Chrome) is not taking the width of the scroll bar into consideration, so anytime the height of the table exceeds the max and triggers an overflow, the table gets scrunched over to the left and some cells in the first column have a very ugly word-wrap applied to them.  Without the overflow/max-height combination, the table width is calculated correctly and there is no overflow.

**[Live Demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8bpyX/2/)**

I found two ways around this, both of which are not feasible...

1. Explicitly set the width on each of the cells (or use `table-layout: fixed`)
2. Use `overflow-y: scroll;` instead of auto which causes the scroll bar to *always* appear, even when it is not needed. What makes this worse is that overflow-y is a CSS3 property.

There must be a better solution!  How can I get a vertical scrollbar on the parent of my table without any word-wrapping?

Comment: Since both IE and Chrome and behaving the same, I assume that they are following the specification correctly.  I am not trying to argue with the spec, I am just trying to achieve the desired result, however possible.

Comment: if it is any relief, you can always reduce the width of the scroll bar. most users use mouse wheel/gesture, and for the ones who need scroll-bar can easily find a 5px wide scroll bar. just saying.

Comment: @Achstar Change the width of the scroll bar?!  That is a OS-setting, is it not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, thanks in part to [kei's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6432256/using-overflow-auto-on-table-parent-element-causes-annoying-word-wrap-in-fir/6432359#6432359).  Using `white-space: nowrap;` does indeed prevent the text from wrapping, but it causes a horizontal scrollbar to appear ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8bpyX/4/)).  To remove the horizontal scrollbar, I just applied 18px of right padding to the table parent and now everything works perfect ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8bpyX/5/)).  Thanks to all who helped!

```
div.dialogBody {
  overflow: auto;
  padding-right: 18px;
  max-height: 400px;
}

div.dialogBody table td,
div.dialogBody table th {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try applying `white-space: nowrap;` to your table, but you'll probably need to adjust `div.dialog`'s width explicitly if you don't want the horizontal scrollbars to appear.

Comment: Aha!  This does indeed produce a horizontal scrollbar.  However, I think I know why.  I think it is because the browser again is not taking the width of the scrollbar itself into consideration.  So, if I add padding to the table parent to accomodate for that width, then this solution works great!  +1 I'll be posting a complete answer shortly